# Reading images and documents

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, updating

How might an old (4+ years) cordova setup load images and documents for display to a user?

Moving to the current Cordova has broken the display of images and documents, but I can't see where I should be looking to fix this. There's a javascript function called fetchFile() which looks promising, but this returns an error and says the file is not available (for .jpg, .pdf and .doc), but I can't see where it would be getting it from. Can anyone suggest where I should look?

Some (but not all) files used the ExternalFileUtil plugin, but the only other plugins I can see are BarcodeScanner and SQLite plugins